# Why did Jabba's skiffs have magnets on them?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi, jabba-the-hutt

In *Return of the Jedi*, after escaping from Jabba's Sail-Barge, R2-D2 land in the Tatooine sand. Luke and the others pick them up with the skiff's magnets.

Why did Jabba's skiffs have magnets in the first place?

Comment: Useful thing for when metal things fall overboard into the sand :)

Comment: Per @DVK's comment, this seems more a common sense question than anything else. It's like asking why starships have landing gear - we see in the film what they're used for.

Comment: @recognizer - bet you 10 pushups there's an EU canon explanation :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I can go one better and offer you a Disney canon explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The brand new (and fully Disney canon) [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!) for the film describes them as "***Cargo magnets***".

> *“We’re on our way!” yells Lando, stepping over a dead guard to get to the controls.*
>
> ***Moments later he is lowering the skiff’s cargo-magnets to pull the droids out of a sand dune.***
>
> *And then they’re away, zooming across the dunes to safety! A final explosion erupts behind them as the sail barge—and a great deal of evil—disappears in a massive fireball.*

Since the skiffs are described (by the old [Star Wars Encyclopedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia)) as being used for transporting **cargo**, it makes good sense that they'd have a way of loading and unloading the skiff without having to make a landing.

> **skiff, desert**
>
> ***A repulsorlift utility vehicle, it was usually used to move cargo** or
> passengers. Tatooine crime lord Jabba the Hutt used a number of skiffs
> as escorts for his sail barge. His henchmen often rushed to a raiding
> site in skiffs while barge passengers enjoyed the battle from a safe
> distance.*
>
> *A skiff deck was completely open, with a control station for the
> driver and sometimes a labor droid at the rear. One repulsorlift
> engine provided forward thrust; the craft was maneu-vered with two
> steering vanes hanging off the back of the hull. A skiff could hold
> more than 100 tons of cargo and reach speeds of 250 ki-lometers an
> hour and heights of as much as 50 meters above the surface. When
> fitted with up to 16 seats, skiffs were used as mass transit vehicles
> on poorer worlds.*

Answer (score 2):

It does have an answer in EU - **Legends**

These skiffs are the *Ubrikkan Industries Bantha-II Cargo Skiff* as named in *The Star Wars Sourcebook*, *Cracken's Rebel Guide* and *Galaxy Guide 7: Mos Eisley*

As a cargo skiff many varients of the Batha-II

> were equipped with retractable magnetic lifters and loading ramps for transporting cargo onto the skiffs deck